# How to install humanoid_navigation ROS kinetic Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, ros, gazebo-simu

When installing ROS Kinetic packages (Ubuntu 16.04), namely humanoid_navigation, it throws an error when executing catkin_make. Without this package, catkin_make runs without error. Everything was done according to the instructions https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/op3/recovery/#op3-manual-installation

```
[ 97%] Building CXX object humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeFiles/humanoidlocalization.dir/src/HumanoidLocalization.cpp.o
/home/user/catkin_ws/src/humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/src/HumanoidLocalization.cpp:23:42: fatal error: pcl/filters/uniform_sampling.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeFiles/humanoidlocalization.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeFiles/humanoidlocalization.dir/src/HumanoidLocalization.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeFiles/humanoidlocalization.dir/src/HumanoidLocalization.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:12108: recipe for target 'humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeFiles/humanoidlocalization.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeFiles/humanoidlocalization.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 97%] Linking CXX executable /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/footstep_planner/footstep_planner_node
[ 97%] Built target footstep_planner_node
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j2 -l2" failed
```

After this error, installed pcl from github https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl in src, ran catkin make, and gave an error

```
/home/user/catkin_ws/src/humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/src/HumanoidLocalization.cpp:23:42: fatal error: pcl/filters/uniform_sampling.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeFiles/humanoidlocalization.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeFiles/humanoidlocalization.dir/src/HumanoidLocalization.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeFiles/humanoidlocalization.dir/src/HumanoidLocalization.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:12108: recipe for target 'humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeFiles/humanoidlocalization.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/CMakeFiles/humanoidlocalization.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

Did you terminate/interrupt any build recently? This might be due to the fact that the object code was not generated successfully. One way is to clean the build and devel folder's associated content with the package and then build again.

UPDATE!!!
So I replicated your problem and followed my steps to solve them. In my case I had issues with my ros_control package and pcl. Not it works. Cheers!!!

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable 
/home/aadi/catkin_ws/devel/lib/robot_state_publisher/state_publisher
[100%] Built target joint_state_listener
[100%] Built target state_publisher
[100%] Built target robot_state_publisher
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

Comment: I already deleted build and devel folders, it didn't help. I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....  This error arises from an unfinished build commonly  due to premature termination during  catkin_make.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in PCL 1.7.2, UniformSampling is located in the "keypoints" module, and in 1.8.0, it has been moved to the "filters" module.

Please check your PCL version

Comment: And which version is needed? PCL 1.7.2?

Comment: @Micha93 PCL 1.8.0

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
wget https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/archive/refs/tags/pcl-1.8.1.zip
unzip pcl-1.8.1.zip
cd pcl-pcl-1.8.1
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo ..
make -j4
sudo make install -j4
cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make
```

If you have installed another pcl version before go to this library and enter

```
sudo make uninstall
make uninstall
```

and then remove this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have a working solution:

```
nano /home/<user>/catkin_ws/src/humanoid_navigation/humanoid_localization/src/HumanoidLocalization.cpp
```

And change to following:

```
//#include <pcl/filters/uniform_sampling.h>
#include <pcl/keypoints/uniform_sampling.h>
```

Then go and run catkin_make with `cd ~/catkin_ws && catkin_make`.

It now should work without any errors.